# Is HttpContext.RemapHandler supposed to change which handler processes request?

Tags: c#, httphandler, remap

The MSDN documentation says:

HttpContext.RemapHandler Method - Enables you to specify a handler for the request.

I am trying to move the processing of the request from one handler to another depending on a condition in the first handler. The HttpContext.RemapHandler method seems to initialise an instance of the second handler but not call the HttpHandler.ProcessRequest method; the response is empty.

Does the HttpContext.RemapHandler method do what I think it should - transfer processing to a new HttpHandler and calling the HttpHandler.ProcessRequest method? Or should I be using another approach such as another method or an HttpModule?

EDIT:
Turns out I should be using a HTTPHandlerFactory. I have the solution working nicely now.

So what exactly is HttpContext.RemapHandler for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.RemapHandler` as you specified, however if another `HttpHandler` calls `RemapHandler` (e.g. ASP.NET MVC which registers `MvcHandler` in `PostResolveRequestCache`) your `IHttpModule` will never fire. This is maybe why `IHttpHandler.Process` was never called.

If this is your issue, you can simply define a route to ignore in `MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes` like this:

```cs
routes.IgnoreRoute("your_path/{*pathInfo}");
```

---

Also, remember that with Visual Studio Web Development Server and IIS6, `RemapHandler` will not work.

Here is an example of how to select the right way to remap the handler based on whether or not Integrated Pipeline is activated AND still be able to access the session:

```cs
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
{
  if (HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline)
    // For IIS 7 and IIS 8
    application.PostAuthorizeRequest += Application_PostAuthorizeRequest;
  else
    // For IIS 6
    application.PostMapRequestHandler += Application_PostMapRequestHandler;
}

private void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.RemapHandler(_myHandler);
}

private void Application_PostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Handler = _myHandler;
}
```

The difference between using a `HttpHandlerFactory` and `HttpModule` in this case is that the latter allows you to decide when to use which `IHttpHandler` regardless of ASP.NET `IHttpHandler` mappings. More on MSDN: [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).

Comment: Clear answer, especially the part about the mvc handler!. Thnx!

Comment: RemapHandler will work fine in PostAuthorizeRequest if you have .NET 2.0 Service Pack 2 applied.